# Debian webserver - Crontab error (not running php script)

Tags: php, debian, scripting, cron

I've a webserver with several sites and I'm trying to run a script by crontab but it gives me a error (126 and 127)

My script is in:

> /var/www/site1/script.php

When I run the command:

> php /var/www/site1/script.php

The script work as normal.

I've created a script.sh that contains

> #!/bin/bash
>
> > /usr/local/php5/bin/php /var/www/site1/script.php

If I run

> sh script.sh
>   Works

In crontab, I've entered this:

> 35 13 * * * /var/www/site1/script.sh

And I get this in syslog

> > Apr 12 13:35:01 webserver /USR/SBIN/CRON[13331]: (root) CMD (/var/www/site1/script.sh)
> >
> > Apr 12 13:35:01 webserver /USR/SBIN/CRON[13330]: (CRON) error (grandchild #13331 failed with exit status 126)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/271900/ubuntu-cronjob-failing-with-exit-code-2

Looks like it's already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try it this way

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /path/to/your/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission issue on the file as explained in the link above, change the file permission to 755